# How to overload the "+" notation in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm trying to overload the notation for `+`. The following doesn't work:

```
Definition my_add (n m :nat):= n + m.

Fail Notation "x + y":= (my_add x y) (at level 50, y at next level).
```

Fails with the message `Notation "_ + _" is already defined at level 50 with arguments constr at level 50, constr at next level while it is now required to be at level 50 with arguments constr at next level, constr at next level.`

Which suggests that I need to bind `x` at level 50.

```
Definition my_add (n m :nat):= n + m.

Fail Notation "x + y":= (my_add x y) (at level 50, x at level 50, y at next level).
```

Fail with `The level of the leftmost non-terminal cannot be changed.`.

I'm sure I have defined this notation before, so perhaps this is a recent change to Coq, or am I forgetting something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbols in notations must have unique precedences and associativity. So for a preexisting notation, no annotation is necessary since it's already set:

```
Notation "x + y":= (my_add x y).
```

For some reason you can set associativity alone. You can also set both level and associativity. In any case, they have to match the preexisting values, if any.

```
Notation "x + y":= (my_add x y) (left associativity).
Notation "x + y":= (my_add x y) (at level 50, left associativity).
```

You can also use notation scopes in order to use the same symbol with different meanings, with various bells and whistles to control how they are set. [See the manual.](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html)